# Create 3D array from 1D array in Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I would like to create 3D array of 1D
I have

```
  let a = ['hello', 'my', 'friend']
```

And I tried to create 3D array like this

```
b = [[['h'], ['e'], ['l'], ['l'], ['o']], [['m'], ['y']], [['f'], ['r'], ['i'] ,['e'], ['n'], ['d']]]
```

but nothing works..

How could I do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using map twice works just fine.

```js
let a = ['hello', 'my', 'friend'];

let result = a.map((word) => word.split('')
.map((letter) => [letter]))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works for me and it is really elegant way of coding:)

Comment: hmm, do you know how could I push values? I just tried   `alert(result[0].push('a')); ` but it gives me an error **Argument of type 'a' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'**

Comment: @Natali you'd need to change that to `result[0].push(['a'])`

Comment: @toskv Works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @toskv ehmm...well, the error is gone, but it alerts now a number...6...And I don't really now why. how could I just push an element?

Comment: @Natali that's actually how it works. [`Array#push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the length of the array it just pushed `['a']` to. You pushed to `[['h'],['e'],['l'],['l'],['o']]`, which was length 5, and after the push, length 6.

Comment: @toskv ok, thank you for explanation, I thought it will alert me message like `h, e, l, l, o, a`. But now I see I have to make first `push` and then `alert(result[0]) ` and it will give me what I want. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 3):

This uses the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to implicitly invoke [`String#[@@iterator]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) for each word and then [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)s each character to a unit-length array:

```js
let a = ['hello', 'my', 'friend'];
let b = a.map(word => [...word].map(c => [c]));

console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
```

If you are attempting to run this using Typescript as a preprocessor, you'll need to call the generically implemented [`Array#slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) on each word instead, since they are Array-like objects (and for some reason Typescript doesn't recognize that):

```js
let slice = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);

let a = ['hello', 'my', 'friend'];
let b = a.map(word => slice(word).map(c => [c]));

console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
```

Comment: @Natali here's a solution that works in Typescript preprocessor

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thank you, I will try you solution now :) And I didn't know before about this Preprocessor thing, I will google it now, so thank you twice ;)

Comment: @Natali Typescript is a preprocessor language that is used to assert strict typing for JavaScript, which is an otherwise loosely-typed language.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts oo..ok..so this is how it calls, i'm beginner in typescript, thank you

Answer (score 0):

here is a more rudimentary option

```
function convertStringIntoArray(str){
    var arr = [];
    var words = str.split(" ");
    for(var j=0; j<words.length; j++){
        var word = words[j];
        var innerArr = [];
        for(var i=0; i<word.length; i++){
            innerArr.push([word.charAt(i)]);
        }
        arr.push(innerArr);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) command returns an array - so by calling it once you will get an array characters.

```
a.map(function(item) { return [ item.split('') ]; })
// [[["h","e","l","l","o"]],[["m","y"]],[["f","r","i","e","n","d"]]]
```

If you call map a second time for each character, you can wrap each item in an array.

```
let b = a.map(function(item) { 
    return item.split('').map(function(inner) { 
                                    return [ inner ]; 
                                }); 
})
// [[["h"],["e"],["l"],["l"],["o"]]],[[["m"],["y"]]],[[["f"],["r"],["i"],["e"],["n"],["d"]]]
```

Comment: This is wrong, try running this and compare the output to OP's request.

Comment: This is my result `"[[["h","e","l","l","o"]],[["m","y"]],[["f","r","i","e","n","d"]]]"`. I can't spot the difference

Comment: `[[["h"],["e"],["l"],["l"],["o"]],[["m"],["y"]],[["f"],["r"],["i"],["e"],["n"],["d"]]]` really?